# iphone 5 showing white strip at bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-5

My app works fine in iphone 4 but my iphone 5 showing this below white strip. I have added
Default-568h.png too but issue is still there. What should I do?

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the resizing masks for the view. Make sure it's set to stretch by height in the Autosizing section of the size inspector in Interface builder. Or set the masks appropriately in code if you're not using interface builder.

Edit---

**In Code:**
see autoResizingMask:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

**Interface builder:**

The Autosizing section is what you want.

Make sure the masks are set like this for the view. You will also want to set the outer bars for any controls. Clicking the bottom bar will tell the button to stick to the bottom of the view for instance.

[image]

Comment: I am using interface builder, kindly cna you elaborate?

Comment: can you tell me how to stretch to height?

Comment: The inner arrows control resizing. The vertical arrows are height. Horizontal width. If you're unsure, it shows you how the view will react when you mouse over the autosizing area.

Comment: Note: this will not work if that whole screen is an image. It will just stretch the image. In that case you need to create a new image that is the size of the iphone 5 screen and load it dynamically based on screen size.

Comment: One more thing. Depending on how you're loading the viewController. If this is the main view controller and you're adding the view controller as a subview of window, you need to set it as the rootviewcontroller of the window instead. In the app delegate just set window.rootViewController = myViewController;

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
yourView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin ;
```